# Get Date as of 4 hours ago

Tags: java, datetime, date

How can I return a Date object of 4 hours less than the current system time in Java?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you're already on Java 8 or newer:

```
LocalDateTime fourHoursAgo = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(4);
```

Or if you want to take [DST (Daylight Saving Time)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) into account (just in case it coincidentally went into or out DST somewhere the last 4 hours):

```
ZonedDateTime fourHoursAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(4);
```

Or if you're not on Java 8 yet:

```
Date fourHoursAgo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

And you want to take DST into account:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);
Date fourHoursAgo = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 17):

The other answers are correct, but I would like to contribute the modern answer. The modern solution uses `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

```
Instant fourHoursAgo = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofHours(4));
System.out.println(fourHoursAgo);
```

This just printed:

```
2018-01-31T15:22:21.113710Z
```

The `Z` in the end indicates that the time is printed in UTC — at UTC offset zero if you will. The `Instant` class is the modern replacement for `Date`, so I recommend you stick to it. The modern API is generally so much nicer to work with, so much cleaner, so much better designed.

Please note the advantages of letting the library class do the subtraction of 4 hours for you: the code is clearer to read and less error-prone. No funny constants, and no readers taking time to check if they are correct.

If you *do* need an old-fashioned `Date` object, for example when using a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change, convert like this:

```
Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(fourHoursAgo);
```

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Of course there are other resources on the internet too, please search.

Comment: Next time just vote for close as dupe instead of posting duplicate answers.

Comment: See your point, @BalusC. I would’ve if I had considered them exact duplicates (there’s a substantial overlap between my two answers, but they are not identical).

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);
calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: `Calendar.HOUR` is 12-hour (AM/PM) based, not 24-hour based. You want `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`. Also, using `Calendar#getInstance()` factory is preferred over constructing a region-specific calendar manually.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to milliseconds, subtract the number of milliseconds in 4 hours, convert it back to a Date.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);
java.util.Date d = c.getTime();
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance() ;
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,-4);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: In this case, add is preferable to roll.

Comment: The roll method does only work between 4:00 (am) and 23:59. Otherwise you will get a wrong day.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Calendar` object and the `add` method.

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -4);
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html