# How to create a Date object, using UTC, at a specific time in the past?

Tags: java, date, utc

Is it possible to create a `java.util.Date` object that is guaranteed to be UTC and at a specific time in the past, like an hour ago or a day ago, and is this a good idea?

I have reviewed the Stack Overflow question 
[get date as of 4 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348525/get-date-as-of-4-hours-ago) and its answers. But I want to avoid having to add more dependencies, like `jodaTime`, and the accepted answer uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` which would be the local timezone, would it not?

Comment: Use the [`java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), and I'm almost positive this question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: the question is if this is possible using specifically java.util.Date, but maybe it's not.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` does not reflect the time zone. When you start talking about "days" or "months", you have to define what you mean, because that depends on your business requirements.

Comment: Java 8 or Java 6/7?

Comment: A `Date` has got no time zone or offset.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Provided it’s not a dupe (which I too think it is) I shall be happy to provide a `java.time` answer, you are right. And include conversion to an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` if this is what the OP needs, for example for a legacy API.

Comment: The `Date` class is long outmoded and poorly designed. Only get one if you need one for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now. Under all circumstances I recommend [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V.Exactly.  Exactly.  `Calendar` tried to (unsuccessfully) patch over `Date`'s problems, but it's just better to move to `java.time`.

Comment: `java.time.Instant` is time zone neutral (just like `Date`), but its `toString` always gives the date and time in UTC. This might be a good choice for you? It’s straightforward to convert it to a `Date`. If you need a date-time that is explicitly in UTC, you need a `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed vividly in the comments, the recommendation is to use the `java.time` package. The easy solution:

```
Instant fourHoursAgo = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofHours(4));
System.out.println(fourHoursAgo);
```

This just printed

```
2018-01-31T14:57:44.667255Z
```

Since UTC time is now `18:58`, the output is what you asked for. The `Instant` itself is offset neutral. Its `toString` delivers time in UTC, but there was no mention of UTC in producing the `Instant`, so whether it gives you what you want, I am not sure. I will give you a result that is *explicitly* in UTC later.

But first, if you do need a `java.util.Date`, typically for a legacy API that you cannot change, the conversion is easy:

```
Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(fourHoursAgo);
System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

On my computer in `Europe/Copenhagen` time zone this printed:

```
Wed Jan 31 15:57:44 CET 2018
```

Again, this agrees with the time four hours before running the snippet. And again, a `Date` doesn’t have a UTC offset in it. Only its `toString` method grabs my JVM’s time zone setting and uses it for generating the string, this does not affect the `Date`. See the Stack Overflow question, [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date), and its answers.

As promised, if you do need to represent not only the time but also the offset, use an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
OffsetDateTime fourHoursAgoInUtc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(4);
System.out.println(fourHoursAgoInUtc);
```

This printed

```
2018-01-31T14:57:44.724147Z
```

`Z` at the end means offset zero from UTC or “Zulu time zone” (which isn’t a true time zone). The conversion to a `Date` is not much more complicated than before, but again, you will lose the offset information in the conversion:

```
Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(fourHoursAgoInUtc.toInstant());
System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

This printed:

```
Wed Jan 31 15:57:44 CET 2018
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial explaining how to use `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using the `java.time` package, as follows:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(4);
Date date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

Gives the following output:

```
2018-01-31T14:58:28.908
Wed Jan 31 20:28:28 IST 2018     //20:28:28 IST is 14:58:28 UTC
```

Which is correctly `4+5:30` hours behind my current time - `Asia/Kolkata ZoneId`.

Comment: It won't work if I use `ZoneOffset.UTC` in both the statements

Comment: Why not `Date.from(Instant.now().minus(4, ChronoUnit.HOURS))`?

Comment: `LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);` & 
`Date date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());` gives the following output: `2018-01-31T18:50:41.519` & `Thu Feb 01 00:20:41 IST 2018`

Comment: @erickson another nice suggestion

Comment: time currently here is the latter one. But the answer which I posted gives same time in both i.e. `2018-01-31T18:50:41.519`

Comment: Its the first code in your edited answer that doesn’t work. It gives you 14:56:24 IST, which disagrees with 14:56:24 UTC, which would have been correct. It’s `Date.toString()` fooling you.

Comment: Yup. Now I see it. I missed the `IST` part in the first code's output. Changing my answer to the correct one.